# jQuery sort array value in sequence

Tags: javascript, sorting, sequence

I have an array like this `[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]` and I want to convert this into `[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,1]` using jQuery. I have no code and no idea how can I do this.

Comment: Have you done any research into Array sort?

Answer (score 29):

You could use [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) by using a temporary object with a hashtable for the same group array. Take from it the length of the used array as group for sorting.

The sorting happens with the group and index.

The result is mapped with index of the sorted temporary array.

```js
var array = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    groups = Object.create(null),
    result = array
        .map((value, index) => ({ index, group: groups[value] = (groups[value] || 0) + 1 }))
        .sort((a, b) => a.group - b.group || a.index - b.index)
        .map(({ index }) => array[index]);

console.log(...result);
```