# Efficient way of alternating sort of array of objects based on property

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, coding-efficiency

suppose we have an array of objects with one property called `cat`.
How can we sort this array alternating the values based on the value of `cat` property on an efficient and cleaver way? suppose category value is always `'a'` or `'b'`.

**given:**

```
[
    {cat: 'a'}, {cat: 'b'},
    {cat: 'b'}, {cat: 'a'},
    {cat: 'b'}, {cat: 'b'},
    {cat: 'b'}, {cat: 'b'},
    {cat: 'b'}, {cat: 'a'}
]
```

**expected output:**

```
[
  { cat: 'a' },
  { cat: 'b' },
  { cat: 'a' },
  { cat: 'b' },
  { cat: 'a' },
  { cat: 'b' },
  { cat: 'b' },
  { cat: 'b' },
  { cat: 'b' },
  { cat: 'b' }
]
```

I implemented the solution bellow, but it seens quite strange:

```
let myArr = [
  {cat: 'a'}, {cat: 'b'},
  {cat: 'b'}, {cat: 'a'},
  {cat: 'b'}, {cat: 'b'},
  {cat: 'b'}, {cat: 'b'},
  {cat: 'b'}, {cat: 'a'}
]

alternatedSort = (it, i, arr) => {
  function findAlternatedValueIndex(lookupIndex, it, arr){
    if(lookupIndex < arr.length && arr[lookupIndex].cat == it['cat']){
      lookupIndex ++
      return findAlternatedValueIndex(lookupIndex, it, arr)
    }
    else 
      return lookupIndex < arr.length ? lookupIndex : undefined
  }

  var lookupIndex = i + 1

  if (lookupIndex < arr.length && arr[lookupIndex].cat == it['cat']){
    let tgtIndex = findAlternatedValueIndex(lookupIndex, it, arr)
    if (tgtIndex) {
      const aux = arr[lookupIndex]
      arr[lookupIndex] = arr[tgtIndex]
      arr[tgtIndex] = aux
    }
  }
}

myArr.forEach(function(it, i, arr) {
  alternatedSort(it,i, arr)
});


console.log("sorted array: ", myArr)
```

***obs**: what is the complexity of the algorithm above and what is the best complexity we could get?*

Comment: another approach may be this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46663239/1447675).

Comment: I might construct a list of [k, ik, o], where ik is the dense rank of k (the key). Then this list can be sorted on ik-then-k and the resulting o (original object) extracted in the target order. This approach will extend to any number of key groups. It is within O(n log n).

Comment: @user2864740 can you give an example or some reference on what do you mean by dense rank? What topic in math/computer science is that?

Comment: @victorisrae I've added an answer with more details and an example.

Comment: Also, my usage of “dense rank” was confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply split the array by `cat` and then merge the results alternating.

```
let cata = arr.filter(x=> x.cat === 'a');
let catb = arr.filter(x=> x.cat === 'b');

let newarr =[];
let i = 0;

while (cata[i] || catb[i]) {
  if (cata[i]) newarr.push(cata[i]);
  if (catb[i]) newarr.push(catb[i]);
  i++;
}
```

That's in *O(n)*, because it's just 3 iterations of the array. And *O(n)* is the best you can get, as you have to look at each element in the array at least once.

Another approach doesn't need to split the array beforhand. It needs a total of 2 iterations through the array (once for each category) and fills the new array while traversing.

```
let newarr = [];
let a = 0, b = 0;
while (arr[a] || arr[b]) {
  while (arr[a]?.cat === 'b') a++;
  while (arr[b]?.cat === 'a') b++;
  
  if (arr[a])
    newarr.push(arr[a++])
  
  if (arr[b])
    newarr.push(arr[b++])
}
```

A completely different approach, doing it in place (but at the cost of an additional property) with the built-in `Array.sort` could be the following

Assign to each element if it's the 1st, 2nd, ... of its category. Then sort by that `order` property. If two elements have the same `order`, sort `a` before `b`

```
let a=0, b=0;
for (let e of arr) {
  e.order = e.cat === 'a' ? a++ : b++
}

arr.sort((x,y) => { 
  if (x.order === y.order) 
    return x.cat === 'a' ? -1 : +1;
  return x.order - y.order;
})
```

Of course this is at least *O(n logn)*, depending on the sort algorithm used by the JS engine.

Comment: you solution is so simple... i knew i was doing too much effort on a simple task. But how about the arr.filter() calls? You are iterating over all the array  on each call, right? If the array was too large it could impact the performance or K * O(N) is irrelevant and equivalent to O(n)? Just wanted to thank you for the answer, now i see how far i am from good coding and how i must back to the foundations of algorithms

Comment: In theoretical computer science O(n) is equivalent to O(k * n) for any *constant* k ( even if it's 1000000000). In a practical use, this constant k may of course be of relevance. For small n and large k, it might even be faster to use an algorithm of a higher class ( n logn, n^2), but that of course depends on the actual data and must be tested with benchmarks

Comment: Furthermore it's often a tradeoff between space and time. As you see in my two approaches, one works in linear time, but needs additional space. The other one doesn't need an additional array, but isn't linear in time

Comment: @victorisrae instead of arr.filter() calls it could be possible to use only arr.reduce() one time and get the values of cata and catb

Comment: @ManuelMB Yes, that might be a possibility. But again, from a theoretical point of view, it doesn't matter wheter the array is iterated once or a 1000 times (unless the number of iterations is constant and does not depend on the size of the input). And for practical use (if it really is about getting the last nanosecond out of an algorithm) one has to do a benchmark anyways ...

Answer (score 2):

This is how I might approach this problem. While it isn't the most efficient, it is mostly likely sufficient efficient, and it is a general approach that applies to any number of keys. Variations of this concept are found relatively routinely in SQL queries.

The steps are as so:

- For every item generate a tuple `[key, rank(key), item]`. Here the `rank(key)` means the ordinal number of the occurrence of the key in relationship to other keys of the same value. There must be no gaps in the rank: that is, there are 1..3 ranks for 'a' and 1..6 ranks for 'b', and 1 for 'c'.
- Sort the tuples by `rank(key)` and then `key`.
- Extract the original `item` values.

Here is the concept in generalized JavaScript. There are libraries that can further abstract this approach.

Initially, given some items in different groups:

```
var items = [
    { cat: 'a', name: 'first a' },
    { cat: 'b', name: 'first b' },
    { cat: 'b' },
    { cat: 'a' },
    { cat: 'b' },
    { cat: 'b' },
    { cat: 'c', name: 'Mr. C' },
    { cat: 'b' },
    { cat: 'b', name: 'last b' },
    { cat: 'a', name: 'last a' }
]
```

Take the items and build a sequence of tuples that contain the rank per occurrence of the key. This is an O(n) operation.

```
var ranks = {}; // key -> last rank (undefined = 0)
var t = [];

for (let i of items) {
  var rk = (ranks[i.cat] = (ranks[i.cat] || 0) + 1);
  t.push([i.cat, rk, i]); 
}
```

Now t is as follows. (The duplication of key is intentional here to explain the concept, as well as for a more generic sort, although the sort could very well access the original object and thus eliminate a tuple index. Likewise, the original objects could be mutated to contain the rank.)

```
[
  [ 'a', 1, { cat: 'a', name: 'first a' } ],
  [ 'b', 1, { cat: 'b', name: 'first b' } ],
  [ 'b', 2, { cat: 'b' } ],
  [ 'a', 2, { cat: 'a' } ],
  [ 'b', 3, { cat: 'b' } ],
  [ 'b', 4, { cat: 'b' } ],
  [ 'c', 1, { cat: 'c', name: 'Mr. C' }, ],
  [ 'b', 5, { cat: 'b' } ],
  [ 'b', 6, { cat: 'b', name: 'last b' } ],
  [ 'a', 3, { cat: 'a', name: 'last a' } ]
]
```

Next, sort by the rank and then the key. This generic sort operation is O(n lg n), making it the algorithm’s big-O.

```
t.sort((a, b) => (a[1] - b[1]) || a[0].localeCompare(b[0]));
```

After the sort, t is:

```
[
  [ 'a', 1, { cat: 'a', name: 'first a' } ],
  [ 'b', 1, { cat: 'b', name: 'first b' } ],
  [ 'c', 1, { cat: 'c', name: 'Mr. C' } ],
  [ 'a', 2, { cat: 'a' } ],
  [ 'b', 2, { cat: 'b' } ],
  [ 'a', 3, { cat: 'a', name: 'last a' } ],
  [ 'b', 3, { cat: 'b' } ],
  [ 'b', 4, { cat: 'b' } ],
  [ 'b', 5, { cat: 'b' } ],
  [ 'b', 6, { cat: 'b', name: 'last b' } ]
]
```

Finally, loop through the tuple and extract the 3rd element, which corresponds with the original object. This is O(n).

```
var interwovenItems = t.map(x => x[2]);
```

Which yields the final result:

```
[
  { cat: 'a', name: 'first a' },
  { cat: 'b', name: 'first b' },
  { cat: 'c', name: 'Mr. C' },
  { cat: 'a' },
  { cat: 'b' },
  { cat: 'a', name: 'last a' },
  { cat: 'b' },
  { cat: 'b' },
  { cat: 'b' },
  { cat: 'b', name: 'last b' }
]
```

Comment: thank you so much for your effort on explain it clear! It will be very useful on my studies. once again, thank you for your support

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to go more generic.  What if we had categories A, B, C, and D and wanted to cycle through them in sequence?  What if the key were in a different property than `cat`?

This solution writes a simple function atop two more generic helpers.  The first one, `group`, is similar to the `groupBy` [functions](https://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) [found in](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupBy) [many libraries](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy), except that instead of returning an object keyed off the supplied function, it returns just an array of the arrays they generate.  It could easily be built atop one of them by calling `Object.values` on the result.

The second helper,  `seqMerge`, takes a array of arrays and rearranges them by picking the first values off each array in sequence, then the second from each, etc, simply skipping each array when it's empty.  It looks like this:

```js
seqMerge ([
  [1, 11], 
  [2, 22, 32, 42, 52, 62], 
  [3, 13, 33]
])
//=> [1, 2, 3, 11, 22, 13, 32, 33, 42, 52, 62]
```

With those, our main function becomes trivial:

```js
const group = (fn) => (xs) => 
  Object .values (
    xs .reduce ((a, x) => ({...a, [fn (x)]: [... (a [fn (x)] || []), x]}), {})
  )

const seqMerge = ([[x = undefined, ...xs], ...xss]) => 
  x == undefined 
    ? xss .length == 0 ? [] : seqMerge (xss)
    : [x, ... seqMerge ([...xss, xs])]


const alternatingSort = (keyGen) => (xs) => 
  seqMerge (group (keyGen) (xs))

const xs = [{cat: 'a', id: 1}, {cat: 'b', id: 2}, {cat: 'b', id: 3}, {cat: 'a', id: 4}, {cat: 'b', id: 5}, {cat: 'b', id: 6}, {cat: 'b', id: 7}, {cat: 'b', id: 8}, {cat: 'b', id: 9}, {cat: 'a', id: 10}]

console .log (alternatingSort (x => x .cat) (xs))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Note that this version allows for as many categories as we like, not only two.  It allows us to decide on a different property to use for partitioning the values, or even allows us to create a synthetic key for that.  But using it is still simple.

### Extensions

There are several ways we might want to extend this.  There might be a reason to sort the groups we're going to yield.  That would just mean doing something like this:

```js
const alternatingSort = (keyGen) => (xs) => 
  seqMerge (
    group (keyGen) (xs) 
      .sort (([a], [b], x = keyGen (a), y = keyGen (b)) => x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0)
  )
```

Or we might note what Rich Snapp has called the [Reduce ({...spread}) antipattern](https://www.richsnapp.com/article/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern), and decide to fix `group` up in a less elegant but more efficient manner with

```
const group = (fn) => (xs) => 
  Object .values (xs .reduce (
    (a, x, _, __, k = fn (x)) => ((a [k] = a [k] || []), (a [k] .push (x)), a),
    {}
  ))
```

or a more imperative version of the same idea.

And, while we're discussing performance, we might want to look at `seqMerge` more closely.  I find that code elegant and quite beautiful.  But it will bottom out when the combined list lengths approach the recursion depth limit, and will likely perform abysmally long before that.  If you're using this for lists a few dozen long, then it won't be an issue.

We could rewrite it atop a `transpose` function.  But it can't be any old transpose.  My default version, `(xs) => xs [0] .map ((_, i) => xs .map (r => r[i]))`, for instance, won't work here.  `transpose` by the way, flips a rectangular grid, over its main diagonal.  For instance:

```js
transpose ([
  [1, 2, 3,  4,  5],
  [2, 3, 5,  7, 11],
  [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
]) //=> 
// [
//   [1, 2, 1], 
//   [2, 3, 4], 
//   [3, 5, 9], 
//   [4, 7, 16], 
//   [5, 11, 25]
// ]
```

but the behavior on a ragged grid is undefined.  And for this problem, we want to include all the results even if the columns aren't the same length.  We can write a version that does so like this:

```js
const transpose = (xs) => Array .from (
  {length: Math .max (... xs .map (r => r .length))}, 
  (_, i) => xs .map (r => r [i]) .filter ((x => x != null))
)
```

And then our sequential merge function is trivial:

```js
const seqMerge = (xs) => 
  transpose (xs) .flat ()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'use strict'

catObjectArray = [
    {cat: 'a'}, {cat: 'b'},
    {cat: 'b'}, {cat: 'a'},
    {cat: 'b'}, {cat: 'b'},
    {cat: 'b'}, {cat: 'b'},
    {cat: 'b'}, {cat: 'a'}
]

catObjectsByType = {
    'a': catObjectArray.filter(object =>  object.cat === 'a').length,
    'b': catObjectArray.filter(object =>  object.cat === 'b').length
}

let totalCatObjects = catObjectsByType.a + catObjectsByType.b

let sortedArrayOfCats = []

while (totalCatObjects !== 0){
    if(catObjectsByType.a > 0){
        if(totalCatObjects % 2 === 0){
            sortedArrayOfCats.push({cat: 'a'})
            catObjectsByType.a = catObjectsByType.a - 1
        } else {
            if(catObjectsByType.b > 0){
                sortedArrayOfCats.push({cat: 'b'})
                catObjectsByType.b = catObjectsByType.b - 1
            } else {
                sortedArrayOfCats.push({cat: 'a'})
                catObjectsByType.a = catObjectsByType.a - 1 
            }
        }
        totalCatObjects -= 1

    } else {
        sortedArrayOfCats.push({cat: 'b'})
        catObjectsByType.b = catObjectsByType.b - 1
        totalCatObjects -= 1
    }
}

console.log(sortedArrayOfCats)
/*
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {cat: "a"}
1: {cat: "b"}
2: {cat: "a"}
3: {cat: "b"}
4: {cat: "a"}
5: {cat: "b"}
6: {cat: "b"}
7: {cat: "b"}
8: {cat: "b"}
9: {cat: "b"}
*/
```